# How can I change the security setting and enable terminal for a Vertex AI managed notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I created a notebook using Vertex AI without enabling terminal first, but I want to enable terminal now so that I can run a Python file from a terminal. Is there any way I can change the setting retrospectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, when you create a Notebook instance with unchecked *"Enable terminal"* like the below screenshot, you **cannot re-enable this option once the Notebook instance is already created**.
[image]

The only workaround is to **recreate the Notebook instance** and then enable it.

Right now, there is already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/222694899) for this. You can **star** the public issue tracker feature request and add **‘Me too’** in the thread. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I've added +1. hope the feature becomes available soon.

Comment: We have a new Update Runtime API Endpoint will see if we can add this option there. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @ScottB - I accepted your answer. I also tried to upvote it but received "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I will try it again once I got more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Just checked in the code, this morning, will rollout to Prod in 2 weeks and you will be able to use Update API method to change terminal. We will expose in UI a way to change this configuration as well. for this I have no ETA.